# How to retrieve data from appsettings.json, when execute Nunit test in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: c#, json, automated-tests, nunit, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a test automation framework for API testing with below structure:
[image: structure]

In appsettings.json file I store any data for tests:
[image]
[image]

I retrieve data from appsettings.json with help of ConfigManager class:
[image]

When I execute my test on my local machine, everything is OK, but when I try to execute it in bitbucket pipeline, I get NullReferenceException (when try to use variable form ConfigManager (e.g. BaseUrl)). Here is my .yaml file:
[image]

If required data is hardcoded:
[image]
test is passed in pipeline run. Therefore, I believe that the problem is precisely in the correctness of data extraction from the json file.

My question: is there anything wrong in my code? Should I add anything in yaml file to be able to get data from appsettings.json?
Any help would be valuable.

Comment: How do you execute test locally?

Comment: Can you check if `appsettings.json` is versioned and present in build result on CI?

Comment: Since you depend on the current directory, add a test to check that the file is present in the current directory when running under CI.

Comment: @Vernou - locally I run with Visual Studio (Test Explorer - Run)

Comment: @Charlie - I have added simple tests
 '        [Test]
        public void CheckFile()
        {
            var info = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            info.GetFiles("appsettings.json").Should().HaveCount(1);
        }'
it is passed on CI

Comment: I think you need remove `SetBasePath`, because `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` can be `dotnet.exe`'s directory.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. In "Core" part of my TAF I used the wrong path to json file for setting up "FlurlHttp.GlobalSettings.Timeout" value. Instead of using ConfigManager class, I was using new configuration, that's why value for timeout was not found. I updated my ConfigManager
[image]
and now everytning works fine in bitbucket CI